# "Assumption of a guarantee for qualities" meaning unclear in warranty terms and conditions

Tags: word-usage, terminology, ambiguity

I've been asked to translate the sentence,

> "The above is without prejudice to further claims in the event of the
>   assumption of a guarantee for qualities."

The phrase "**assumption of a guarantee for qualities**" seems unclear to me in this context.

Does it refer to an assumed guarantee in the event of transferred ownership (e.g. buyer B purchases the article in question from buyer A, thus assuming the ownership of the guarantee as well)?

Or does it refer to an assumed guarantee that is not explicitly defined in the warranty terms and conditions but is either assumed to be valid nevertheless as per to good common practice (or perhaps by law)?

Can there be another interpretation I am missing altogether?

Answer (score 1):

More context might be necessary, but it may mean a company taking up guarantor obligations in the event of their taking over or merging with another company.

https://www.lawinsider.com/clause/assumption-of-the-guarantee

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to a wider context myself. "The above" in this phrase refers to the warranty period for the purchased article. I suppose that, as I was able to find the same lawinsider.com article as you, that I will go with my first interpretation of the matter. Thank you, but I am still willing to hear others' views on this!

Comment: "assumption of a guarantee for qualities" is unclear and doesn’t look at all like mainstream English.

Generally we might expect “a guarantee of quality” but isn’t that different? Don’t you think in legal, rather than general English, it matters even more… so you should go to a legal forum. There, ask yourself how it’s possible you don’t have access to context, and this matters?

The phrase clearly doesn’t refer to any *period* for anything. If it did, it would be either something specific you’re quoting, or some kind of general theory with no useful context.
Can’t you say which, please?